# Mixing Qt and boost causes compilation error with "check" keyword

Tags: qt, boost

I am using Qt in a project and am now trying to include another project that uses boost. 
I have added no_keywords to my config in the qt project file to avoid collision between the signal and slots functionality that is present in boost and Qt. But now I get a compilation error which seems to stem from double definition of a function called "check". Is there some way to avoid this?

An example is has_postfix_operator.hpp (line 141):
static ::boost::type_traits::yes_type check(has_operator); // this version is preferred when operator exists

Apparently there is a "check" defined in Qt.

I'm using Qt4.7 and boost 1.48. Running MacOSX 10.6.8

Answer (score 3):

You should also look at /usr/include/AssertMacros.h, which defines a macro named "check" - that could be the cause of your problem.

To check this, add -d __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES=0 to your compiler flags.
If that works, that was your problem.

Here's a comment from that file:

> Prior to Mac OS X 10.6 the macro names used in this file conflicted
>   with some user code, including libraries in boost and the proposed C++
>   standards efforts, and there was no way for a client of this header to
>   resolve this conflict. Because of this, most of the macros have been
>   changed so that they are prefixed with 
>   __ and contain at least one capital letter, which should alleviate the current and future conflicts.  However, to allow current sources to
>   continue to compile, compatibility macros are defined at the end with
>   the old names.  A tops script  at the end of this file will convert
>   all of the old macro names used in a directory to the new names. 
>   Clients are recommended to migrate over to these new macros as they
>   update their sources because a future release of Mac OS X will remove
>   the old macro definitions ( without the double-underscore prefix ). 
>   Clients who want to compile without the old macro definitions can
>   define the macro
>   __ASSERT_MACROS_DEFINE_VERSIONS_WITHOUT_UNDERSCORES to 0 before this file is included.